# Rで算術演算子の代わりと成る関数は存在しますか？

Tags: r

Rで算術演算子（`+, -, *, /`）の代わりに関数で計算したいです。

`+` ならば `sum` がありますが、`-, *, /`の機能を行なう関数ないしパッケージはありますでしょうか？

自分で関数を設定してもいいのですが、毎回設定するとやや手間になるのでできれば既成の関数を使いたいです。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

二項演算子の関数バージョンという意味ならば, Rは演算子も関数として扱われます.

例:

```
'+'(1, 2)
'+'(c(1, 1), c(2, 3))
```

詳しくはこれらを参考にしてください
https://igjit.github.io/slides/2018/01/tiny_pipe/#/

http://www.okadajp.org/RWiki/?R%E3%81%AE%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0%E5%AE%9A%E7%BE%A9%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC